# Log-transforming an IV that uses count data & showing diminishing returns

Tags: nonlinear-regression, negative-binomial-distribution, logarithm

I am currently running a negative binomial model which has a count variable as the DV.
One of my predictors is the count of previous alliance experiences and my hypothesis is that there are diminishing returns to experience.

By log-transforming my IV, I significantly increase model fit and the significance of the predictor. However, I have read on several sources that there are barely any good reasons to log-transform a count-IV.

Hence, I am wondering whether this result is simply a coincidence or whether there indeed is a rationale behind log-transforming this variable?

Furthermore, I have to test for diminishing returns. My initial idea was that a log-transformation proves diminishing returns, as the incremental effect of a higher number of experiences is lower after a log transformation. However, my superviser states that this does not prove diminishing returns and that I have to include a squared term to do so. Is this indeed the case? 
My ideas was that if the linear effect of ln(x) on y is significant, the non-linear effect of x on y should also be significant and hence show diminishing returns. Where is the flaw in this logic?

Comment: A count variable can be zero so logs are problematic. I would rather use regression splines.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Only less than .5% of my count data has a value of zero, hence I applied a log-transformation to the data and put a value of zero for the few cases where the count was zero as well.